# Why is my HTML link not replacing the whole URL?

Tags: html

I have a search engine using PHP/MySQL. I use this code to display the results from MySQL:

```
echo "<table width='300px'>
   <h4><a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a><br />
   $desc<br>
   <font color='red'>$url</font></table></h4>
   ";
   }
?>
```

However, if I add a URL (for example `www.google.com`) and I click on the title, it links me to `http://mysite.com/www.google.com`, instead of `http://www.google.com`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the PHP code that assigns a value to `$url` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$url` is "www.google.com", which is not a complete URL.

Consequently, your HTML looks like this (you should have posted the resulting HTML, really, as PHP has nothing to do with this):

```
<table width='300px'>
<h4><a href='www.google.com'><b>sometitle</b></a><br />
somedescription<br>
<font color='red'>www.google.com</font></table></h4>
```

`www.google.com` is not a full URL, and so your browser is treating it as a relative path, and thus prepending the current domain.

Your `$url` should be a full URL, like `"http://www.google.com"`.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your URLs with `http://` ie. `http://www.google.com`

You could do it this way:

```
<a href='http://$url'><b>$title</b></a><br />
```

Comment: i want the link to open in a new page so i put target="_blank" but it shows a php error

Comment: You need to put `target='_blank'` or escape your quotes `target=\"_blank\"`

Comment: do i have to put http:// before $url so that it won't go to mysite.com/www.google.com